# Bash script for re-encode file if re-encoded file does not already exist for all in directory

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, encode, aac

I have a bash script that takes 1 argument (a file) and runs an ffmpeg command to create a duplicate of the file encoded with a different codec.

```
#!/bin/bash

ffmpeg -i "$1" -vn -acodec aac "$(basename "${1/.wav}").aac"
```

I just want to modify this bash script so instead of taking an argument, it instead just checks for all files in the directory to see if the re-encoded file already exists, and if it does not, creates it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks for your help

EDIT: the solution below is working with slight modification:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./*.wav; do
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue # check if any file exists
    if [[ ! -f "${file}.aac" ]]; then
       ffmpeg -i "${file}" -vn -acodec aac "$(basename "${file}").aac"
    fi;
done;
```

Comment: You want to process all files ending in .wav?

Comment: If what you want is not to overwrite an existing file then just use the `-n` option of `ffmpeg`.

Comment: _for all files in the directory_ Which directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to process all files ending in "*.wav" in a directory. In your bash script you can use `find` like `find . -type f -name "*.wav"` and  or `ls` with `grep` like `ls -1 | grep "*.wav"` to get the specific codec file names. Then you combine this with something like `sed` or `cut` to drop the file extensions and just check if the same file exists with the different codec for each file name. In this case, for example, you can modify your script to:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(ls -1 | grep ".wav" | sed -e 's/\.wav$//'); do
  if [[ ! -f "${file}.aac" ]]; then
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -vn -acodec aac "$(basename "${file/.wav}").aac"
  fi;
done;
```

This will create the file with the different codec if it does not exist.

Edit:

From the feedback received in the comments, I think a better answer would be using globbing to allow the shell to expand patterns into a list of matching filenames like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for file in ./*.wav; do
    [ -e "$file" ] || continue # check if any file exists
    if [[ ! -f "${file%????}.aac" ]]; then
       ffmpeg -i "${file%????}" -vn -acodec aac "$(basename "${file}").aac"
    fi;
done;
```

Comment: Not my down-vote. This could be helpful: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: I believe `$(find . -type f -name "*.wav" | sed -e 's/\.wav$//')` would achieve the same result.  (Don't worry about the down-vote, everybody is trying to be helpful to the community in their own way.)

Comment: Both `for f in $(find ...)` and `for f in $(ls ...)` patterns are fatally flawed beyond any repair. Please read [Bash Pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: Thanks @M.NejatAydin, edited the answer in an attempt to make it better with feedback!

Comment: Thank you very much! Your second idea worked great with this slight modification: I just changed 
`ffmpeg -i "${file%????}"`
to
`ffmpeg -i "${file}"`

Answer (score 0):

Emm, Try

```
#!/bin/bash

#construct filename
filename="${1/.wav}".aac;

#check file exists
if [[ -f $filename ]];
then
echo "Em, File "$filename" Exists :)";
else
ffmpeg -i "$1" -vn -acodec aac "${1/.wav}".aac
echo "Finished Processing..$1..Done"
fi;
```

Comment: This does not answer the poster's question. It's misleading.

Comment: The poster writes "instead of taking an argument, it instead just checks for all files in the directory to see if the re-encoded file already exists". The script should not take an argument. It should check all files and encode the ones that are not yet encoded.

Comment: How will you find out _which_ re encoded file exists?? Without any argument??

Comment: Your making up your _own_ question _for him_ . Your basing your assumption on the other answers you've read without asking for any input or classification from the OP.

Comment: If you need clarification, you could post a comment on the original question. From my perspective the question is quite clear.

Comment: It's _very clear_ from my perspective as well??

Comment: thank you roccobaroccoSC